# How to convert the binary file into a hexdump in SAS

Tags: binary, sas, hexdump

For example, PNG file d:\aaa.png, Now I want to use SAS to convert d:\aaa.png binary file into a hexdump. Thank you. In R,redBin function can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for.  It reads the file one character at a time and writes the HEX representation to the outfile.

```
%let infile = "C:\temp\SGPlot.png";
%let outfile = "c:\temp\out.txt";
filename infile &infile;
filename outfile &outfile;

data _null_;
infile infile recfm=n;
file outfile recfm=n;
format c $1.;
input c $ @@;
put c hex. @@;
run;
```

Comment: Can you upload your file SGPlot.png, I will paste the reslut from another software. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot upload my png and reslut file. Can you tell me your email. I will send these files to you. You may upload these files. Thanks!

Comment: just use your file and compare the output form SAS and R.  I don't understand why you need my file.

Comment: max.bytes<-50000000;dat<-readBin("c:/data/mpg.png", what="raw", size=1, signed=TRUE, endian="little",n=max.bytes);    Your sas results were different with R results.

Comment: put c hex. @@;   How to put uppercase into lowercase？

Comment: Your sas code wasn't correct because the results were different with R results.